# Stripping Headers/Footer from Plain Text Email Content

Tags: c#, email, text, text-processing

Has anyone used/recommend any services/products/tools that have been successful at stripping header and footer content and chain replies from plain text e-mail content?

I have several years of e-email content from a CMS and I'm being asked to do a sentiment analysis and produce a dashboard based around sentiment.

I'm trying to remove anything that would dilute/pollute the actual message sentiment.

Thanks,

Steve H

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic on SO. But maybe we can push you a step further or two? Can you make some assumptions and check those about the emails? For example: Will they have very similar headers/footers? When they contain replies, are those marked and are they sorted in one specific way or do you see any combination of sorting / marking / nonmarking that's out there? Can you work with the email "raw" data or do you just have text (or html) ? ... Maybe you want to classify and approach each class differently? That way you may be able to get to a 90% automatic solution and ...

Comment: ... be left with 10% that need manual interaction to some degree?